# ServiceStack Utility to read from Custom Config Sections

Tags: servicestack

Is there any ServiceStack utility that can read from custom config sections. ServiceStack has IAppSettings which makes it easy to read from appSettings in a config file. I am wondering if ServiceStack has a similar utility to read from Custom Config Sections.

Thanks
rudrvij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't, we actively discourage usage of Config Sections which is XML encumbered, in-flexible, non-portable and non-substitutable.

Our preference (when needed) is instead to embed Complex Type configuration in a [single AppSetting Text Value](http://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings#example-usage) which is transparently supported using the [human-friendly JSV Format](http://docs.servicestack.net/jsv-format), e.g:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="RedisConfig" 
         value="{Host:localhost,Port:6379,Database:1,Timeout:10000}" />
</appSettings>
```

Which is supported by every [App Settings Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings#ormlite-appsettings) and can be easily serialized into any POCO with:

```
RedisConfig redisConf = appSettings.Get<RedisConfig>("RedisConf");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.